# when transfering from sub-address index, remaining monero is moved to index 0

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc, sub-address, transfer

I received payments into a subaddress of my wallet account and created a transfer from that subaddress for a portion of the funds using the RPC wallet. However, after the transaction was created all the remaining funds that had been in the subaddress were moved out and into subaddress 0.

Is that expected behaviour? I'd like to keep the funds in the subaddress, is there a way to specify that in the transfer?